# echo json and include_once $SESSION

Tags: php, jquery

```
cart = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test/shop.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            get: "all"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("got it!");
            refreshTable(data);
            $('#cart table').hide().fadeIn('fast');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Ajax request failed: ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

shop.php

```
$json_a = json_encode($_SESSION['cart']);
echo $json_a;
```

I want to include the shop.php so it can be reached from all files.
But when shop.php is included the echo json prints to the screen as well. How do I prevent this?

Comment: use a conditional that checks the current page you're accessing and just don't run that piece of code.

Comment: Wait... What? What's wrong with what you have currently? It seems fine.

Comment: **You don't include** a file that you access via AJAX, that's why you use AJAX!

Comment: scrowler Ok so do you have a solution? Still need that session and the ajax request.

Comment: @user2402963 my suggestion is to read some tutorials on this before you ask about it here. Hint: leave shop.php alone and call it with AJAX, you don't need to include it just because it has session variables - they will work just like any other script in your current session...

Comment: **Note:** pay attention to what Madara Uchiha said - what you've **shown** us is fine, and is how you should do it. Whereever you're **including** this code, just don't do it. Use what you've shown us.

Comment: Ok will see what I can find on AJAX. Thanks

Comment: AHA. Well that was easy enough...